# Ruby on Rails + HTML + CSS, if checked, strike through

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am still working on my cookbook app. I am at the point of building out the grocery list feature. From the recipe page, you will be able to click a link "Add to Grocery List" and you will be taken to a page with all the ingredients from that recipe.

The goal is to have the ingredients listed one by one, with a checkbox beside each ingredient. When the box is checked, I want the ingredient to be striked through like so, <s>Eggs</s>. When the box is unchecked I just want it to be normal text. This is where I need your help. Obviously I'm going to need some If statements but I'm unsure how to build those with these desired elements.

I have ingredients setup via **text_area** so in-order to differentiate between ingredients you must use the **each_line** function.

Here is what I have so far, this is from the **_grocery** partial:

```
<% @recipe.ingredient.each_line do |line| %>
  <li><%= line %></li>
<% end %>
```

I am not using bootstrap, so I don't have the foggiest idea of how to do the **checkbox** and **<s>strike through</s>** if the checkbox is checked. Any insight anyone can provide will be much appreciated, If you need more code from me, let me know and I'll promptly provide such.

I am quite far outside my depth on this one.

Comment: You can do this with just CSS3 - what does the HTML of one line (checkbox and ingredient) look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manage the strike-through using CSS only. To save the state of the item, however, you would ideally use AJAX to save the form automatically, otherwise, you could add a "Save List" button and it would all be set up like a normal form in Rails.

Below is an example of using CSS to dynamically strike the item when checking the box, or when the box is checked on page load.

```css
.row input:checked + span {text-decoration: line-through}
```

```html
<div class="row"><input type="checkbox"> <span>My item</span></div>
<div class="row"><input type="checkbox"> <span>My item</span></div>
<div class="row"><input type="checkbox"> <span>My item</span></div>
<div class="row"><input type="checkbox"> <span>My item</span></div>
<div class="row"><input type="checkbox"> <span>My item</span></div>
```

When you initially load the page, you would use ruby to determine if the checkbox *should* be checked or not (which is easy with Rails' form helper). You will let CSS do the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

To further `Wes Foster`'s epic CSS-only answer, I'll cut to the chase for you...

---

What you're asking is a front-end styling issue, *not Rails*.

Although you've provided great context with your information, it seems to me that you  may have an issue recognizing the specific aspects of how the system should fit together.

---

> I have ingredients setup via `text_area`

I'll provide some code (the above is a *bad move*).

Wes has the answer; this should help you with the efficiency of what you're doing:

```
#app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
end

# join table - ingredients_recipes - ingredient_id | recipe_id

#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
end
```

The main structural issue you have is you're manually adding "ingredients" to a recipe. You'll be MUCH better suited to using a `many-to-many` relationship (either [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) or [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)) to associate different records.

In short, this will allow you to use the following:

```
@recipe.ingredients.each ...

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @recipe = Recipe.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/recipes/show.html.erb
<% @recipe.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %>
    <%= content_tag :li, ingredient, class: "ingredient" %>
<% end %>

#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
li.ingredient:checked + span {  /* Wes's code */ }
```

This will provide you with a list of `ingredients` for your `recipe`.

---

If you wanted to add/remove ingredients to a recipe:

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
end

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @recipe = Recipe.new
   end

   def create
      @recipe = Recipe.new recipe_params
      @recipe.save
   end

   def edit
     @recipe = Recipe.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @recipe = Recipe.find params[:id]
      @recipe.update recipe_params
   end

   private

   def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:recipe, :params, :ingredients)
   end
end
```

Doing this will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/recipes/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe, method: :put do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :ingredients, @recipe.ingredients, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to show the existing `ingredients` for your `@recipe`, updating them on submit.